# How to generate PDF from a selected cell area of a spread sheet with Google script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my original spreadsheet seen below.

[image]

I am trying to create a PDF from my google sheet with a press of the "export PDF" button.

I have a problem trying to generate the PDF based on a **selected cell** on my google-sheet. (On the Left side, Leave the menu area out)

I have tried a few methods but seem not able to solve it.

```
var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getRange("A1:I37").getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
```

...But it generates the entire Spreadsheet still.

I just want to generate a PDF from `A1:I37`

Could someone see my code and guide me?

```
  function generatePdf() {
  // Get active spreadsheet.
  var sourceSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // Get active sheet.
  var sheets = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  var sheetName = sourceSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getName();
  var sourceSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName);

  // Set the output filename as SheetName.
  var pdfName = sourceSheet.getRange(6,8).getValue() + "_" + sourceSheet.getRange(17,11).getValue() +"_"+ sourceSheet.getRange(8,4).getValue();

  // Get folder which to save pdf in.
  //var parents = DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).getParents();
  var date = new Date();
  var year= date.getFullYear();
  var mt = date.getMonth();
  var month     
  if  (mt === 0) {
   month = "January";
  }if (mt === 1) {
   month = "February";
  }if (mt === 2) {
   month = "March";
  }if (mt === 3) {
   month = "April";
  }if (mt === 4) {
   month = "May";
  }if (mt === 5) {
   month = "June";   
  }if (mt === 6) { 
   month = "July"; 
  }if (mt === 7) {
   month = "August";  
  }if (mt === 8) {
   month = "September";  
  }if (mt === 9) {
   month = "October";  
  }if (mt === 10){
  month = "November";
  }else if (mt === 11){
  month = "December";
  }
  var parents = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("Cliff Q "+month+" "+year);
  Logger.log(parents)
  if (parents.hasNext()) {
    var folder = parents.next();
  }
  else {
    folder = DriveApp.getRootFolder();
  }

  // Copy whole spreadsheet.
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

  // Delete redundant sheets.
  var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
  for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
      destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
     Logger.log(destSpreadsheet);

    }
  }

  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  // Repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references).
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,37,9);
  var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1,1,37,9);
  destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);


  // Save to pdf.
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  // Delete the temporary sheet.
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}'''
```

**Updated**

I tried deleting the 3 right columns but my buttons will still appear on the PDF.
The code and resulted PDF can be seen below.

```
    '''// Copy whole spreadsheet.
  var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))
  var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

  // Replace cell values with text (to avoid broken references).
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getMaxRows(),sourceSheet.getMaxColumns());
var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getDisplayValues();
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1, 1, destSheet.getMaxRows(), destSheet.getMaxColumns());
destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);

// Delete redundant sheets.
var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
destSpreadsheet.deleteColumns(10,1);

}
}

  // Save to pdf.
  var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
  var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

  // Delete the temporary sheet.
  DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
}'''
```

[image]

Is there a better way to do this or a way to hide the buttons.

Reply to 
[image]

Here is the PDF Screenshot which you have given. 
The buttons are still there and the whole spreadsheet is exported instead of the selected area.

I have squared out the area i want to export.

Comment: You say this doesn't work - what is the error you are getting? Or if you aren't getting an error, what is your output?

Answer (score 0):

When my understanding of your situation is correct, I thought that in your script, the following issue might occur.

- When `destSpreadsheet` is exported as a PDF file, the result of `destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);` might not be reflected to the Spreadsheet.
- Because `var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0]` has the values in the cells, the range except for `getRange(1,1,37,9)` might be left.
- The cell format except for the range of `getRange(1,1,37,9)` is left.
- The source sheet includes the values retrieved from other Spreadsheet. For example, `IMPORTRANGE` is used.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Flow:

The flow of this modification is as follows.

1. Insert new sheet in the source Spreadsheet as the temporal sheet.
2. Copy the values and cell format from the active sheet to the temporal sheet with the range of `getRange(1,1,37,9)`.
3. Copy the source Spreadsheet as the destination Spreadsheet.
4. For the source Spraedsheet, delete the temporal sheet.
5. For the destination Spreadsheet, delete the sheets except for the temporal sheet.
6. Export the destination Spreadsheet as a PDF file.

#### Modified script:

When your script is modified, please modify as follows.

From:

```
// Copy whole spreadsheet.
var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))

// Delete redundant sheets.
var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != sheetName){
    destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
   Logger.log(destSpreadsheet);

  }
}

var destSheet = destSpreadsheet.getSheets()[0];

// Repace cell values with text (to avoid broken references).
var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,37,9);
var sourcevalues = sourceRange.getValues();
var destRange = destSheet.getRange(1,1,37,9);
destRange.setValues(sourcevalues);


// Save to pdf.
var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().getAs('application/pdf').setName(pdfName);
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

// Delete the temporary sheet.
DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
```

To:

```
// --- Below script was added. 
var tempSheetName = "tempSheet";

// var tempSheet = sourceSpreadsheet.insertSheet(tempSheetName); // <--- Modified
var tempSheet = sourceSheet.copyTo(sourceSpreadsheet).setName(tempSheetName); // <--- Added
tempSheet.clearFormats(); // <--- Added

var srcRange = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,37,9);
var dstRange = tempSheet.getRange(1,1,37,9);
srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, {contentsOnly: true});
srcRange.copyTo(dstRange, {formatOnly: true});
tempSheet.getImages().forEach(function(e) {if (e.getAnchorCell().getColumn() > 9) e.remove()}); // <--- Added
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
// ---

// Copy whole spreadsheet.
var destSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.open(DriveApp.getFileById(sourceSpreadsheet.getId()).makeCopy("tmp_convert_to_pdf", folder))
sourceSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(tempSheet);  // <--- Added

// Delete redundant sheets.
var sheets = destSpreadsheet.getSheets();
for (i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
  if (sheets[i].getSheetName() != tempSheetName){ // <--- Modified
    destSpreadsheet.deleteSheet(sheets[i]);
    Logger.log(destSpreadsheet);
  }
}

// Save to pdf.
var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().setName(pdfName); // <--- Modified
var newFile = folder.createFile(theBlob);

// Delete the temporary sheet.
DriveApp.getFileById(destSpreadsheet.getId()).setTrashed(true);
```

#### Note:

- When `destSpreadsheet.getBlob()` is used, this mimeType is `application/pdf`. So you can use `var theBlob = destSpreadsheet.getBlob().setName(pdfName)`.

#### References:

- [insertSheet(sheetName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#insertSheet(String))
- [deleteSheet(sheet)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet)
- [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)
- [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush)

If I misunderstood your situation and this was not the direct solution of your issue, I apologize. At that time, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to modify it.

Comment: Hi thank you so much for your answer. It does the work of copying, pasting and exporting to Pdf of the selected area I want. Unfortunately, It lost all the images in the form. I will post the spreadsheet images for your reference

Comment: @Cliff Choo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. I couldn't suppose that from your question, your source Spreadsheet includes images. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that didn't work for your Spreadsheet, I apologize. At that time, I would like to confirm your sample Spreadsheet.

Comment: Hey Tanaike, there is no need to say sorry. Let's hope our discussion can help others in the future. I added pictures below.

Comment: @Cliff Choo Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current situation and your goal. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. Can you provide a sample Spreadsheet and the output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information. I would like to support you. By the way, when you add more information, please add them to your question. When you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Cliff Choo Thank you for updating your question. For your updated question, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? I removed the images outside of the range by adding `tempSheet.getImages().forEach(function(e) {if (e.getAnchorCell().getColumn() > 9) e.remove()});`. In this case, the images outside of the column "J" are removed. If you want to expand the removed images, please reduce the number of `9`.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, thank you so much for your follow up answer. I tried replacing the code but i get the whole spreadsheet exported and the buttons are still there.

Comment: @Cliff Choo Thank you for replying. From your replying and adding the output image, I thought that the button might be not images, and those buttons might be by drawing. In this case, unfortunately, in the current stage, the button put by drawing cannot be managed by the script. I think that this might be the current specification at Google side. So as one of workarounds, how about replacing the buttons to images which are PNG and JPEG? By this, the above modified script can be used.

Comment: @Cliff Choo Or, as other workaround, if the image of the upper left in your bottom image can be put from Google Drive or URL, this can be used as the workaround. How about this? I deeply apologize that I cannot find the method for managing the buttons put by drawing.